# Java print only the last loop value

Tags: java, loops

I have following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int x = 1; x < 6; x = x + 1) {
            System.out.println(amount= amount * 9 / 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the program takes user input and to calculate six monthly payments **with any kind of loop**. Monthly interest of 10% is deduced out of the main debt. So for instance, if one inputs 10000, the output is:

```
10000
9000
8100
7290
6561
5904
```

I need only to print the last value, in this case 5904. Again, I need to use loop, not to simply calculate the rest value. How could I set the loop to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `System.out.println` call to outside the loop. Inside the loop do the calculation of the amount. Outside the loop print the final result, namely:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int x = 1; x < 6; x = x + 1) {
            amount = (amount * 9) / 10;
        }
        System.out.println(amount);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb now :D But hopefully I'll learn more :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just move the print statement outside the loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 6; x = x + 1) {
    amount = amount * 9 / 10;
}
System.out.println(amount);
```